# Iterating over a sorted array to remove duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, iteration

Let me start by saying this a homework question that I am having trouble with.

I have sorted an array and what I need to do is use another array to remove duplicates by iterating over the first and comparing adjacent items then adding the non duplicates to the new array.  Once I have finished that I set the old array = to the new array.  I am not used to java and therefore I am running into some problems I think getting the iteration setup correctly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    args = new String[] { "data/list1.txt" };
    StdIn.fromFile("data/list2.txt");
    // StdOut.toFile ("finished.txt");
    int[] whitelist = In.readInts(args[0]);

    Arrays.sort(whitelist);
    int newArray[] = new int[whitelist.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < whitelist.length-1; i++) {
        int k = 0;
        if(whitelist[i+1] > whitelist[i])
            newArray[k] = whitelist[i];
            k++;
        StdOut.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(whitelist));
        whitelist = newArray;
        }
    for (int i=0; i<newArray.length;i++){
        StdOut.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(newArray));
    }
```

This code piece is part of a larger binary search, but this is the portion I am having problems with.

My output besides not having the duplicates removed also prints out several times.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Regarding the output issue, you're looping over the array and printing the whole thing each time. Just one call to `StdOut.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(newArray));` at the end is enough.

Comment: Try deciding where braces should go after your `if(whitelist[i+1] > whitelist[i])` statement. Change it to `if(whitelist[i+1] > whitelist[i]) {` and decide where the `}` should go.

Comment: I would step through your code in your debugger to understand what it is doing.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  When I step through the debugger it seems as if the whitelist[i+1] > whitelist[i] statement is not doing anything.  Am I adding the value incorrectly to the new array that I have created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the limitations like not using collections, your code can be rewritten this way, and it will work:

```
    Arrays.sort(whitelist);
    int newArray[] = new int[whitelist.length];
    newArray[0] = whitelist[0];
    int k = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < whitelist.length - 1; i++) {
        if(whitelist[i+1] > whitelist[i]) {
            newArray[k] = whitelist[i + 1];
            k++;
        }
    }
    newArray = Arrays.copyOf(newArray, k);
    whitelist = newArray;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.  I got close to this but was a little off.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` only applies to the first instruction, k++ is incremented in each iteration. You should use:

```
if (whitelist[i+1] > whitelist[i]) {
        newArray[k] = whitelist[i];
        k++;
}
```

Also, in the first loop you are overwritting the `whilelist` with `newArray` even after the first operation, I think you meant to move this outside the `for`:

```
StdOut.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(whitelist));
whitelist = newArray;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try these changes and then looking at my debugger to see if I can spot why the duplicates still are not being removed.

Answer (score 0):

It could help you start any work by outlining the algorithm on paper, it will help when you have to code for interviews.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you should correctly define equals() and hashCode(), to define what the word "duplicate" means for your objects. But since you use primitives and wrappers (through boxing/unboxing) you don't have to do it here.

Then you should put your array into some Set collection. All duplicates will be eliminated automatically. After that put the Set back to Array.

The Java built-in mechanism will remove duplicates in the most optimized way.
You will not have to do it manually.

```
    Integer[] whitelistI = null;
    Set set = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(whitelist));
    whitelistI = (Integer []) set.toArray(new Integer[set.size()]);
```

If you need an array of primitives you can copy it from whitelistI.

Moreover, this is wrong:

```
int newArray[] = new int[whitelist.length];
```

Your new array will be of the same length as the original one, but you said you want to delete duplicates.
If you delete duplicates its actual size becomes shorter and your new array will have empty values (in your case - 0 (zeros)).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I know about the set collection but we are not allowed to use it here.  I am not concerned about the 0's quite yet as I have not been able to delete the duplicates yet by adding the unique values to the new array yet.

Comment: In your code above while iterating over whitelist you modify it in the cycle.

Comment: Why if you can use Arrays and sort you cannot use Collections?